# Javascript handling multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I'm making a webpage with a submit form where you can submit multiple time periods. On each period you can add extra comments when you click on a checkbox. This works fine for 1 period but when I add more periods with .clone() in jQuery it alters all checkboxes.

How should I resolve this problem?

Comment: Without some code and some markup we would only be guessing at a solution to your issue. Can you provide some of that? Maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: Show HTML you selecting and jQuery selectors you use.

Comment: Here you go :) 
http://jsfiddle.net/P3URK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in javascript codes.
First, you have to show/hide textbox only for that section. In order to do this, you can use `closest()` and `find()` methods of jQuery.
Secondly, when checking checked property, it is better to use $(this) of jQuery because javascript's this is something different there.
Finally, when clonning an element you should use `true` parameter if you want to clone actions of elements, too.

Working codes are:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#tijdstiptoevoegen").on( "click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
          $( ".tijdstip" ).clone(true).appendTo( ".tijdstippen" );
    });

    $(".chkUitleg").on("change",function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest(".tijdstip").find(".verdere_uitleg").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).closest(".tijdstip").find(".verdere_uitleg").hide();
    }
});
  });
```

Comment: However when I click on add tijdstip the second time I gives me 2 tijdstippen instead of 1.

Comment: If found the solution.

`var i = 0;
var cloneid = $( '#tijdstip'+ i );
var prev = i;
var previd = $( '#tijdstip'+ prev );
i = i + 1;
$( previd ).clone(true).attr('id', 'tijdstip'+(i) ).find("input:text").val("").end().insertAfter( cloneid );`